# Dropdown bind method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

I have a method:

```
public IEnumerable<Company> Select()
{
   DataClassesCompanyDataContext dc = new DataClassesCompanyDataContext();
   System.Data.Linq.Table<Company> company = dc.GetTable<Company>();
   Company com = new Company();
   return dc.Companies.OrderBy(e => e.company_id);
}
```

By this I want to bind dropdown.

I am using this method:

```
private void fillCompanyNameDropdown()
{
    PioneerDataAccess.CompanyClass comp = new PioneerDataAccess.CompanyClass();
    var objcomp = comp.Select().ToList();
    ddlCompanyOff.DataSource = objcomp[0].company_name;

    ddlCompanyOff.DataBind();
}
```

But the problem is that if the company name is `pulil` then it shows

```
p
u
l
i
l
```

So what can I do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for you...this will might resolve your issue

```
var objcomp = comp.Select().ToList();             
ddlCompanyOff.DataSource = objcomp ;
ddlCompanyOff.DataTextField = "company_name";              
ddlCompanyOff.DataValueField = "company_name";              
ddlCompanyOff.DataBind();
```